# How to push data to an iphone app?

Tags: ios, push

I'm new to iphone app development and I'm having trouble figuring out how to push data to the app. Specifically, I am trying to find a way to push new data (user posts) from the server to the app without the user having to refresh (pull down to refresh). Is is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a close solution

use Apple Push Notification service : it will allow you to send an alert with a message and a button for the user to open the app if you want, it can also add a numbered badge to the icon of your app (think whatsapp, mail).

here's a link explaining how to use it
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

That's the closest you can get, you can't do anything with the iphone if the app is not opened by the user