# Delivering data to iOS and Blackberry

Tags: ios, blackberry, push, pull

Good Day,

We are outsourcing the development of a mobile app for our customers. We will be targeting the two major brands within our target market: iOS and Blackberry. Android is not yet popular, and will be deferred. The app will be written in the platform's native SDK. The app is completely data driven, with data retrieved (pull and push) over the open internet.

I am responsible for the delivery of the data, and haven't been able to decide on what delivery mechanism to use. Our backends are all in-house developed. I'm wanting to use open standards for delivery of the data to both types of handsets.

I would prefer to use the same mechanisms for both iOS and Blackberry.

What would you suggest that I make use of for push and pull? Native functionality is preferred.

I was thinking of JSON over HTTP for pull and XMPP for push.

Comment: FYI: Android:Microsoft:Blackberry:Apple market share in our target audience is around 0.5%:2%:30%:60%. We will eventually add support for Android and Windows Mobile. We won't be using a cross-dev framework, to exploit native functionality.

Comment: AFYI: the push will be around one update per second, with each update having in the region of 40-400 bytes of data.

Comment: If you are avoiding using native Push mechanisms for devices and want to stick to  using the Internet as your distribution network then this [realtime web technology guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) should be of use to you, and a good starting point for investigating web technologies. I'd recommend looking at WebSocket solutions since it's a stable standardised solution good server and client library support, and is bi-directional meaning you can use one technology for all communication.

Answer (score 0):

Think in the Android world, like in the enterprise world, RESTful web services is a common pull technology. Not sure what the equivalent would be for BBM but suspect the server side would be pretty similar. It's just HTTP after all. For iOS, check out http://restkit.org/

Not sure about push. This looks interesting though:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670097/how-to-push-data-to-an-iphone-app
```

Hope this is some help.

Comment: I'm not looking for push notifications (although this may be a future requirement), but to stream data to the app. The user will have the app streaming only when they need it - i.e. when it is open.